# Get image with given url and convert it to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, image, file, uri

I have an image url (http://example.com/myimage.jpg) and want to convert it to byte array and save it in my DB.

I did the following, but getting this message `URI scheme is not "file"`

```
URI uri = new URI(profileImgUrl);
File fnew = new File(uri);
BufferedImage originalImage=ImageIO.read(fnew);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos );
byte[] imageInByte=baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)) for `File(URI)` constructor specifies that the uri has to be a "File" URI. In other words, it should start with "file:"

> **uri** An absolute, hierarchical URI with a scheme equal to "file", a
>   non-empty path component, and undefined authority, query, and fragment
>   components

But you can achieve what you are trying to do by using an URL, instead of a File/URI:

```
URL imageURL = new URL(profileImgUrl);
BufferedImage originalImage=ImageIO.read(imageURL);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos );

//Persist - in this case to a file

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("outputImageName.jpg");
baos.writeTo(fos);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Why not save the bytes directly, doing via an image is surely a big overhead?